# Objective-C HMAC 256 difference against Node.js

Tags: javascript, objective-c, node.js

Folks,

I'm trying to generate a Hmac256 digest but am obtaining different results in node.js and objective-c. Not sure why.

Here's the node code which I believe to be right.

```
var crypto = require('crypto')
var result = crypto.createHmac('sha256', 'mykey').update('mydata', 'utf-8').digest('base64');
```

And here is my Objective-c code:

```
const char *cKey = [@"mykey", cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
const char *cData = [@"mydata" cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

unsigned char cHMAC[CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];

CCHmac(kCCHmacAlgSHA256, cKey, strlen(cKey), cData, strlen(cData), cHMAC);
NSData *HMAC = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:cHMAC length:sizeof(cHMAC)];
NSString *hash = [Base64 encode:HMAC];
```

Anyone has any idea on where the reason for difference can be?

Comment: Is your key purely printable ASCII's, or is it binary? If it's binary, then at least: (1) you don't tell node that when you invoke `createHmac()`, and (2) you use `strlen()` on it, which is probably wrong for binary.

Comment: FIrst get both to work with just the input data so that the output data matches. Then add UTF-8 and base64.